# GulpJS: Assertion Error when trying to automate all tasks to form CSS files from SASS files

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp

I have a problem regarding my task automation. I am using gulpJS and my css used is gulp-sass. I tried to learn this from a youtube video I found online -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYbt50dhTko and my main problem is, I tried to automate my css so that I won't have a hard time compiling both my css and sass files but I always get an error that says:

```
assert.js:339
throw err;
^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] 
(C:\Users\Applicant\Documents\responsive_screen\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task 
(C:\Users\Applicant\Documents\responsive_screen\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Applicant\Documents\responsive_screen\gulpfile.js:22:6)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
```

This is my first time coding in gulp js and I really want to learn this one. I will post my source code below this paragraph:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var uglifycss = require('gulp-uglifycss');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('css', function(){
    gulp.src('./css/*.css')
    .pipe(uglifycss({
        "maxLineLen": 80,
        "uglyComments" : true
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./sass/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
 });


gulp.task('run', ['sass', 'css']);

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('./sass/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('./css/*.css', ['css']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['run', 'watch']);
```

Can someone share solutions or ideas to this problem? It would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Replace each occurence of this pattern `['taskname']` with this pattern`gulp.series('taskname')`. You are using a newer version of gulp with a newer syntax.

Comment: You saved my life! Thank you so much, @TheDancingCode! :D

Comment: how can I automate this though? so that whenever I save, I no need to input gulp in CLI @TheDancingCode

Comment: Isn't that what your watch task does?

Comment: yes. but it doesn't work. i get "undefined" as a result. @TheDancingCode

Comment: Can you ellaborate on that `undefined` result? What error do you get?